# LTI System and Output Signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 systems [H]: y(n) = x(2n), [G]: y(n)=x(n).x(n-1).x(n-2) – 2y(n-1) 
1. How can i check if whether 2 systems above is LTI or not? i can't use num,den, and filter function for those function.
2. How can i simulate the output signal with input x(n) = (0.5).^ .*u(n) ? 
Thank you for helping me.
And how can i simulate the impulse response of G and H ?

Comment: You need maths, not Matlab, to determine whether these systems are LTI.

Comment: For H, what is y(3) for example? I don't think you have a correct question

Comment: @percusse: y(3) is x(6) - it's just the equation for a downsampler.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah my mistake. What I mean is x is the state of the system. if there is no input it doesn't make sense as a downsampler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please explain "." in G and ".^.*" in x. It is not really clear.

1.Question: See https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Showing_Linearity_Time_Invariance.html

2.Question: The simulation is not difficult, because it is normal algebra. Firstly, the input signal is created:

```
u=rand(1,50); % 50 random values between 0 and 1
```

Then, x can be calculated.

```
x = 0.5.^u;
```

For H, the command is very simple:

```
y = x(1:2:end);
```

For G it is a little bit more difficult. The simplest solution would be a loop (or a function). An idea would be:

```
y2=zeros(1,length(x));  
for n=3:length(x)
 y2(n)=x(n)*x(n-1)*x(n-2)-2*y2(n-1);
end
```

An alternative solution would be with a Simulink model.

Comment: that's not what the question asks I'm afraid

Comment: @percusse Well, I remember similar tasks from university. u is most likely the input signal, x is a state and y is the output signal. G and H are different functions that should be investigated. It is very obvious that G and H cannot be LTI-Systems. A downsampler is not time invariant and G is not linear due to the multiplication. How did you understand the question?

Comment: Yes but you didn't show the non-LTIness. you just supply some x

Comment: He has two questions: 1. The first question is about the non-LTIness for which I posted a link where you can find examples. It is pretty simple math. The second question is about simulation. I made some random input signal because it is not specified.

Comment: Thank you so much, and i have another questions, how can i simulate the impulse response of G and H. ,how can i find the impulse response and output of cascade H->G->I with I=y(n) = 2x(n) –x(n-2) – 0.5y(n-1).